# Bad Receiver Type 'CGRect'

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, receiver

I'm trying to pass a CGRect into an objective c function as follows:

```
+(UIImageView *) detectEdges: (UIImageView *)_sourceImageView withCropRect:(CGRect)_cropRect
{

   [_cropRect topLeftCornerToCGPoint:[(NSValue *)[sortedPoints objectForKey:@"0"] CGPointValue]];
   [_cropRect topRightCornerToCGPoint:[(NSValue *)[sortedPoints objectForKey:@"1"] CGPointValue]];

   //code continues
```

Everytime I refer to `_cropRect` I get a compiler error: `"Bad Receiver Type 'CGRect'"`. Why is this happening and what should I do to rectify it?

Comment: `CGRect` is a structure, not a class. It *knows* no `topLeftCornerToCGPoint:` method. If you are using some 3rd party code/repos please add reference.

Comment: I'm trying to pass _cropRect in from another class. I can pass in the UIImageView but not the CGRect. I don't know why I can't pass the CGRect into the function.

Comment: You *can* pass it into the function, but you can't send it a message (`topLeftCornerToCGPoint`).   The top left corner can be had by de-referencing the CGRect struct (not an object) using `_cropRect.origin`

Comment: @Tom: are you trying out [MMCamScanner](https://github.com/mukyasa/MMCamScanner) or something?

Comment: Yes Rok, I'm trying to use it with some swift code but as you can see my objective c skills are low.

Comment: Well that method is written in a subclass of `UIView` subclass and you are trying to use it on a CGRect - that is not even a class but a structure. You could write a function that takes a `CGRect` and a `CGPoint` and sets a specific corner to given point. One should take care of negative widths or heights in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the methods `topLeftCornerToCGPoint:` and `topRightCornerToCGPoint:` can only be used on `MMCropView` instances. Unfortunately I do not know the framework or what you are trying to achieve; but you shouldn't be calling these on `CGRect`.